# daemon socket listening in background for request

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have two process: `daemon` and `client`. Both are different sockets. Initially I execute deamon socket by
`./daemon` and then `./client`.

But I wanted that daemon process should listen in background always for the  request from client. So using `fork()` I tried to create such a process.

I just edited the original code.

Now when I can compile daemon files and create executable `daemon`.

But when I send request `./client` it does not respond. And says `error connecting socket 111`.

`daemon` is listening on `1104` and client sending request on the same. 
When I exucte `./daemon` it says 
`Error binding to socket, make sure nothing else is listening on this port 22n`

Means it running in the back ground but not responding on request.
Code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

#include "dictionary_exclude.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"

#define CHECK_THROW(condition, code) if(condition) throw code
void *SocketHandler(void *);
int OpenSocket();
int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    int host_port = 1104;
    char buf[20];
    int k;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    int hsock;
    int *p_int;
    int err;
    socklen_t addr_size = 0;
    int *csock;
    sockaddr_in sadr;
    pthread_t thread_id = 0;

    try {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    CHECK_THROW(pid < 0, -5);
    if (pid == 0) {
        mode_t umask(mode_t mask);
        pid_t childid = setsid();

        hsock = OpenSocket();   // Function call for hsock
        CHECK_THROW(listen(hsock, 10) == -1, -4);
        my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);

        memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
        my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        if (bind(hsock, (sockaddr *) & my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error binding to socket, make sure nothing else is listening on this port %dn", errno);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        if (listen(hsock, 10) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error listening %dn", errno);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        //Now lets do the server stuff

        addr_size = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

        while (true) {
        printf("waiting for a connectionnn");
        csock = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
        if ((*csock = accept(hsock, (sockaddr *) & sadr, &addr_size)) != -1) {
            printf("---------------------nReceived connection from %sn", inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr));
            pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, &SocketHandler, (void *) csock);
            pthread_detach(thread_id);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %dn", errno);
        }
        }           //while end
    }           //if (pid) end
    }               //try

    catch(int ierror) {
    switch (ierror) {
    case -4:
        fprintf(stderr, "Error listening %dn", errno);
        break;
    case -7:
        fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %dn", errno);
        break;
    }
    }

}

int OpenSocket()
{
    // Create your socket and return the socket handle from this function 
    int hsock;
    int *p_int;
    hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (hsock == -1) {
    printf("Error initializing socket %dn", errno);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    p_int = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p_int = 1;

    if ((setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1) || (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *) p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1)) {
    printf("Error setting options %dn", errno);
    free(p_int);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    free(p_int);
    return hsock;
}


void *SocketHandler(void *lp)
{

    //some procesing
}
```

Can some one say is there any problem in above code.

Original code was:

```
int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    int host_port = 1104;
    char buf[20];
    int k;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    int hsock;
    int *p_int;
    int err;
    socklen_t addr_size = 0;
    int *csock;
    sockaddr_in sadr;
    pthread_t thread_id = 0;

    try {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    CHECK_THROW(pid < 0, -5);
    if (pid == 0) {
        mode_t umask(mode_t mask);
        pid_t childid = setsid();

        hsock = OpenSocket();   // Function call for hsock
        CHECK_THROW(listen(hsock, 10) == -1, -4);
        my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);

        memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
        my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        if (bind(hsock, (sockaddr *) & my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error binding to socket, make sure nothing else is listening on this port %dn", errno);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        if (listen(hsock, 10) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error listening %dn", errno);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        //Now lets do the server stuff

        addr_size = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

        while (true) {
        printf("waiting for a connectionnn");
        csock = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
        if ((*csock = accept(hsock, (sockaddr *) & sadr, &addr_size)) != -1) {
            printf("---------------------nReceived connection from %sn", inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr));
            pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, &SocketHandler, (void *) csock);
            pthread_detach(thread_id);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %dn", errno);
        }
        }           //while end
    }           //if (pid) end
    }               //try

    catch(int ierror) {
    switch (ierror) {
    case -4:
        fprintf(stderr, "Error listening %dn", errno);
        break;
    case -7:
        fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %dn", errno);
        break;
    }
    }

}

int OpenSocket()
{
    // Create your socket and return the socket handle from this function 
    int hsock;
    int *p_int;
    hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (hsock == -1) {
    printf("Error initializing socket %dn", errno);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    p_int = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p_int = 1;

    if ((setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1) || (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *) p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1)) {
    printf("Error setting options %dn", errno);
    free(p_int);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    free(p_int);
    return hsock;
}

void *SocketHandler(void *lp)
{

    //some procesing
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) (the `nc` command on Linux) to test basic connectivity to your daemon? Also note that when you fork() you should, in the child, close all the filehandles you're not using.

Comment: Also please edit your code. Try not to mix tabs and spaces. Use consistent indentation. Please.

Comment: @PP: thanks, daemon is running in 1104. So how can i test? i did with `nc -l 1104` which goes in listening mode

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `listen` before you call `bind` - you should call `bind` first.

Actually, you are calling `listen` twice, both before and after calling `bind`. Remove the first call.

```
hsock = OpenSocket();
// remove this line:
CHECK_THROW(listen(hsock, 10) == -1, -4); 
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
```

Another improvement: use `strerror` or `perror` to generate the error message so that you get a user friendly message. For example:

```
perror("Error binding to socket");
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I removed 2nd listen. But I think `bind` is alredy before `listen`. I would highly appreciate if you can answer with corrected code. I am wandering for this issue last 2 days! if you can help

Comment: @Karimkhan you still haven't indented your code! It's all well and good asking people to solve your problem but if you can't be bothered to even indent your code then it comes across as **very lazy** and you'll inspire nobody to put any effort into helping you.

Comment: @PP: I already indented after your comment. I used online code indenter.

Comment: @Joni: After removing the line you said significant improvement. I need to excute once `./daemon` but then it responde for 1st request `./client`. for next requests it says `Error connecting socket 111
`

Comment: You really should start using `strerror` or `perror` in your programs: error 111 is `Connection refused`. It means that the client program tried to connect to a port that had no server listening. You should post a new question with the problem you are having with the client, including the code of the client there.

Comment: @Karimkhan **you did not indent your code**. What is wrong with you? Your `if` bodies are not indented. Your `try` bodies are not indented. If you're not going to bother to even look at your own code then why should *anybody* else?

Comment: @PP.: Dude i used online code indentation tool. And code looks enough clear.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty easy:
No need for big coding, just `&` will do everything.

inplace of executing `./daemon` use `./daemon &`. This will keep daemon processing listening in back

Comment: That's not how you make a daemon.